# Django w/ Apache, CSRF Verification Failing

Tags: django, apache, csrf

I have a bit of an issue with CSRF verification in my Django app. I have two other `{% csrf_token %}` tags in my app, in two different HTML templates. These work fine, and always have. When attempting to add a third in another new template though, I receive the '403 Forbidden' page. I've copied the style of the two working 'post' commands exactly, but for some reason this one will not work. Any suggestions?

The 'post' form contains a single select/drop-down object, and a submit button. Clicking the button should direct to a view to process the posted data, written again just like the first 2, but it throws the 403 error instead, with the reason for failure being 'CSRF token missing or incorrect'. I'm running Django 1.4.22 also, with User authentication enabled. Here is the not-working view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

...Other Views...
@login_required
def Process(request, id):
    ...
    try:
        choice = request.POST['choice']
    except(KeyError, Item.DoesNotExist):
        return render_to_response('app/home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        ...Process posted data...

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.display', args=()))
```

Here is the working view:

```
#Same includes/imports as earlier, in same file
@login_required
def Submit(request, id, id_2, data):
    try:
        new_data = request.POST[data.name]
    except(KeyError, DataPoint.DoesNotExist):
        return render_to_response('app/home.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        ...Process new data...
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.Data_View', args=()))
```

And here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<table>
<tr><td>
<form action="/app/page/to/redirect/to/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name="choice">
        <option name="yes" value="yes" selected>Yes</option>
        <option name="no" value="no">No</option>
    </select>
</form></td></tr>...</table>
```

Comment: Did you added csrf_token to the render context in the view? can you show your view?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have no csrf_token mention in any view, including those that work. Just in the templates.

Comment: you have to use `from django.core.context_processors import csrf` or `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect` or some other method from [django csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/)

Comment: I tried adding the first import line you suggested but no change. I don't have anything like that otherwise however and the other 2 still work.

Comment: Please, show you work and not work views, edit your question.

Comment: Edits have been added.

Comment: You **should not** use such an old and unsupported version of Django. It is totally insecure and unsafe.

Comment: I would use 1.11, however the machine acting as the server can not run farther than 1.4.22.